# Prove that if $M$ is positive definite, the Schur-complement is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

If
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
  A & B  \\
  C & D 
 \end{bmatrix}$$
is a positive definite $n\times n$ Matrix, prove that the Schur-complement
$$S=D-CA^{-1}B$$
is invertible. Can anyone help? The hint in my textbook tells me to show that $A$ is invertible first.

Actually my argumentation of why $A$ has to have full rank was wrong, so I deleted this part.

Comment: What is your definition of positive definite?  Does positive definite imply symmetric for our purposes?

Comment: Good question. My textbook doesn't specify it more closely. I simply assumed that positive definite means that all Eigenvalues are strictly bigger than one.

Comment: That is *never* what positive definite means!  Do you mean bigger than $0$?  Also, do you mean that the eigenvalues are necessarily real?

Comment: You are right, I wasn't aware of that. I assume the textbook meant positive definite in the sense that $x^tAx>0$ for all $x$, so that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: That's usually what it means.  It's another matter whether $A$ is necessarily invertible

Comment: Isn't it necessarily invertible in that case? I mean if $A$ is not a bijection, then there is a $x\neq 0$ so that $Ax=0$, which implies $x^tAx=0$

Comment: Excuse me! "whether $A$ is necessarily symmetric" is what I mean.

Comment: Just curious, in what context did this come up? Wondering since we only need invertibility of $M$.

Comment: ah ok I see :) thanks for the clarification anyway. For some reason I was believing that positive definite means that all Eigenvalues are positive, which is actually only the case if the matrix is Hermitian. I guess since in physics most matrices are Hermitian I was mistaking the two statements to be equivalent.

Comment: It came up as exercise (3.7.1) in Wolfgang Hackbusch's book on Hierarchical Matrices. I am not sure why positive definiteness was given - invertibility is definitely enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one quick way to see it:
I don't think positive definiteness is very necessary (it's overkill).

Now the Schur complement of $A$ shows up from multiplying $M$ by $$U = \begin{bmatrix}
I & -A^{-1}B \\
0 & I
\end{bmatrix}$$
So that $$MU = \begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\
C & D -CA^{-1}B
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The determinant of $U$ is $1$, so this shows that $\det(M) = \det(A)*\det(S)$.  The determinant of $M$ is positive since it is positive definite, so both $\det(A)$ and $\det(S)$ are non zero.  In fact positive definiteness of $M$ implies $\det(A)$ is positive, so $\det(S)$ is positive too.  In any case, nonzero determinant implies $S$ is ivertible.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer!